# Open a materialize modal not working with if codition

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I want to open a modal window when some conditions are met. I looked for some code and tried to implement it however, it does not work for me.

I have a If condition also in place could that be the reason?

Complete JS code:

```
  <script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
  });

  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',dostuff);


function dostuff() {
    var userinfo = {};

    userinfo.firstname = document.getElementById('nm').value;
    userinfo.email = document.getElementById('mail').value;
    userinfo.process = document.getElementById('process').value;

    if (userinfo.firstname == "" || userinfo.email == "" || userinfo.process == "Choose your option"){

        alert("Hello, \n\nAll Fields are required.\n\nPlease Select all the Fields.");

    } else {       
        google.script.run.userClicked(userinfo);

        document.getElementById('nm').value = "";
        document.getElementById('mail').value = "";
        var selc = document.getElementById('process')
        selc.selectedIndex = 0;
        M.FormSelect.init(selc);

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var Modalelem = document.querySelector('.modal');
            var instance = M.Modal.init(Modalelem);
            instance.open();                         
        });
    }        
}
```

Please focus on the below mentioned code as this is my real concern:-

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var Modalelem = document.querySelector('.modal');
            var instance = M.Modal.init(Modalelem);
            instance.open();
```

Comment: Are you seeing that `alert`? Does the `.init` / `instance.open()` code work if you move it out of that `if/else`?

Comment: Yes It works great if I put the code above do stuff() function.

Comment: Right, then `dostuff()` isn't being executed.

Comment: well dostuff() is being executed I can assure that.

Comment: Then you should be seeing the `alert`, the modal, or errors in your console.

Comment: well the do stuff get executed as it is able to do what it was command by collecting data to a sheet. But the `.modal` should populate right after which is not happening currently.

Comment: here is the [Link] (https://script.google.com/d/1WrBZWABQuwd4-SLu6WJofp1L5TxVdvKu-7bP_q99_Tu-F8P8G1HeCAtl/edit?usp=sharing) if you would like to edit or take a look.

Comment: @Mask How is `doStuff` called?  The mentioned code that you focused on only adds a event listener and won't execute in the ``else`` part.

Comment: @TheMaster I have just added the remaining code. I have also posted my script link in previous comment. Its a copy so you can have a look and even edit.

Comment: `var Modalelem = document.querySelector('.modal');
            var instance = M.Modal.init(Modalelem);
            instance.open();` should be outside the function/ event listener

Comment: ok But how do I do that as conditions are inside the `doStuff`. Do you have any workaround?

Comment: One solution I came up with is declaring a global variable `var x=0;` and in the `else` statement of `dostuff` to make it `x=1` and then passing the `if(x>0)` statement but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Mask I said Should be outside the anonymous function not  outside `doStuff` function

Comment: Thank you @TheMaster it worked. I also found there was no use of  `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {` so i removed it from code.